# The App keeps asking for permission to "Have offline access", why?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

After having authorized the app with oAuth2 and acquiring permissions for requested scopes, I still get a screen asking if I grant the app permission to **Have offline access**, each time I try to login with Google oAuth2. Isn't it something that shouldn't appear again, once I grant it permission to have it?

[image]

Comment: What URLs are you redirecting to?

Comment: What do you mean? To URL that handles authorization code and logs the user in.

Comment: What parameters are you passing to Google's OAuth endpoint?

Comment: Related discussion on github; about IdentityServer but details of Google OAuth2 relevant https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2373

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you use the `approval_prompt` parameter? Try not to ask for offline access again if you already have an refresh token. It should stay valid even if the user logs in again, without requesting offline access.

A reference about this can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=de#formingtheurl).

Comment: And are there any other possible values for approval_prompt, other than - force? Google client library seems to send it by default (had to check the source).

Comment: The other value is `auto`.

Comment: It seems the behaviour is different when developing on localhost.: Regardless of `approval_prompt` value you will always get the "Have offline access".

Answer (score 13):

This prompt could come because of two parameters,

- access_type  (if it is 'offline')
- approval_prompt (if it is 'force')

make sure you have set access_type to 'online' and apporoval_prompt to 'auto'

```
 $client->setAccessType('online');
 $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto') ;
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that your app has approval_prompt=force to force the OAuth each time. Since the user has already authorised whatever scopes you requested, there is no need to repeat them. However the screen has to say something, so in the absence of any better ideas, Google requests 'offline access".

Just make sure that you are not forcing auth and you should be fine.

Comment: I checked and google client library seems to send approval_prompt=force by default. Is this what you mean? I do not see any other params in the url having word force in them.

Comment: yes that's the one. I've edited my answer to correct the parameter name

Answer (score 6):

This is not an error. This is the normal scenario of google oauth2.

**First Process consent as follows:**

1. User consents to the application getting information about the user.
2. When user clicks Accept button, browser will save consent info into cookie and google account will save permission (please view https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions)

**From Second Process:**

Browser checks cookie consent permisson of google account.

- If cookie exists in browser and has permission for this application (https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions): consent screen will be ignored
- If cookie exists in browser but does not have permission for this application: consent screen will be displayed
- **If cookie does not exist in browser: application will display 'Have offline access'.**

Answer (score -1):

Most probably this is very normal according to the incremental auth mechanism and its design, The idea is if a user has already granted the permissions to an app, there is no need to show the same permissions and ask the user to approve.

http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html